# Notification on Samsung Note 9 not working

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-8.1-oreo

Android Oreo notification is working fine on emulator but not working on Samsung Note 9. Can anyone suggest me any solution? The notification manager code snippet as follows for Oreo:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id_com_app_android")
.setOngoing(false)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_2)
.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color))
.setLargeIcon(convertToBitmap(getApplication().getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)))
.setContentTitle(EmojiUtil.decode(name))
.setContentText(EmojiUtil.decode(message))
.setTicker(EmojiUtil.decode(message))
.setStyle(notiStyle)
.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);
builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
builder.build();

NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("channel_id_com_app_android", getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
notificationChannel.setLightColor(R.color.accent_color);
notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

Comment: try register notification channel before building notification

Comment: Let check in settings does notifications from your app is allowed.

Comment: @mostafa3dmax where i put register notification channel?

Comment: @grabarz121 where is it sir?

Comment: in android settings

Comment: before `NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new`

Comment: One user complained she is not receiving notification at all and another user complained she got the notification but no sound (We are using custom sound which works okay on emulator)

Comment: @grabarz121 One who didn't get notification said she enable all settings

Comment: @mostafa3dmax still not working
help me please

Comment: I have a similar issue on my Note 9.  If I set me notification for 5 minutes time, it works fine. If I set it for the next day, it doesn't come.  Worked fine on my Pixel 2 XL.